# Prevent users from accessing mp3s in my uploads folder?

Tags: uploads, htaccess

I have mp3 players set up to play mp3s on my site. The mp3s are all being uploaded to the uploads folder. I don't want people accessing these directly, meaning I don't want people to be able to download the mp3s. Is there a way to somehow restrict access to all files ending in .mp3 in the uploads folder while still having them playable in the mp3 players on the site?

Comment: You will need to upload the files to a location outside of the web root. This is the only sure-fire way of preventing them being downloaded directly. You would then need some PHP mechanism to do whatever it is you are doing with them (streaming them?).

Comment: Is it possible to obfuscate the links so users have a harder time downloading?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple approach to hold download access on your file.

**1.** Using .htaccess:

Upload a .htaccess file into your wp-content folder. Have a look if one exists already, then append this code to the end of the file. If you don’t have one, just create a new blank file and add this code to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(mp3|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3|mp4|mov)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [NC]
```

This rather strange sounding code is neither Linux nor PHP nor MySQL – it’s Apache (that’s the service which usually takes care of serving up those websites from a server). These are instructions that will tell Apache to do the following – I’ll explain this line by line.

Here are some instructions I’d like you to use in this directory:

> 1. IF someone comes from anywhere other than yourwebsite.com
> 2. AND they ask for a direct file that ends with any of the following (mp3, mp4, mov, etc)
> 3. AND they are not logged into WordPress on this domain
> 4. THEN direct every link to such files to http://yourwebsite.com

If these conditions are not met, then give out the file – everyone’s happy.

**2.** Using [Hide Real Download Path](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-real-download-path/) plugin:

This plugin helps you to hide real/direct path of files hosted on your server for download and make your files secure from unauthorized download. It also maintains a log of all downloads done using it and provide capability to disallow direct linking (hot linking) to your files from 
other website.

With this you can:

> 1. Allow or restrict hotlink (direct download) of your files from other website/external links.
> 2. Restrict 'download only' from link on your website
> 3. View log of individual download

It support multiple files extensions including:

> zip / pdf / doc / xls / ppt / exe / gif / png / jpg / jpeg / mp3 / wav
>   / mpeg / mpg / mpe / mov / avi / xlsx

I hope this help you better. Let me know if there is any query regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one of two ways.

1) Simple way. Create a new file in your mp3 directory called index.php, and add this code to it

```
<?php
    // Display no content
?>
```

What this is doing is when a user goes to browse your directory, the web server will serve them the index.php file. Since there is no code in it, the user will be served a blank webpage as a result.

2) Do this through `.htaccess`
In your website's root directory should be a `.htaccess` file. Open this up and add something like

```
Redirect 403 /mp3/ http://mysite.com
```

The Redirect will automatically redirect anyone who tries to access the /mp3/ folder and send them to your main website of mysite.com. The 403 tells the browser that the request is Forbidden.

Comment: #1 won't help if the user knows the name of the MP3 file already. #2 will stop the MP3s being accessed in any way, which is probably not what is desired.

Comment: All valid points. Perhaps you're better off using some sort of download manager plugin, where a download link expires after X amount of tries. Where X is a definable number (1, 3, 5, etc). That's for download. If you're uploading, perhaps just giving your upload folder an obscure name? Even if you did do some htaccess magic, direct links to the MP3 would still work, much like option 1.

Comment: Appreciate the help here, guys. I'll see about it another way then.